# Is avoiding having the fields representing the same object in different communicating classes reasonable?

Tags: java, design, coding-style, coupling

I'm developing a program which does communication to different types of devices (with respective protocols). It should concurrently acquire messages from devices and write them to a file with specific format. Timing is very strict, therefore it's decided to be implemented as 2 threads - one getting messages from device and the second - writing them. The common object for both threads is a message queue.

There is a thread `DeviceHandler`, which starts acquisition thread `DeviceDriver`. In my opinion, `messageQueue` object should belong to `DeviceHandler` and is redundant to be at `DeviceDriver` and increases coupling. I decided to pass it to `DeviceDriver`'s `acquire` method which should start this thread, but I don't know how to combine these both without making `messageQueue` an instance variable.

Moreover, since getting messages from devices is a big task, implementors of `DeviceDriver` use their own message requestors, which in turn should somehow get queue and actually fill it by messages. The same problem here. Also, due to implementation details, `DeviceBDriverRequestor` might be run as a thread.

[image: class diagram]

So I have questions:

1. Am I right avoiding making `messageQueue` an instance variable of DeviceDriver? Or is it acceptable to have it everywhere?
2. What would be a good way to implement `DeviceDriver` class (combination of `run()` and `acquire(Queue messageQueue)` methods) in a way I proposed?
3. Are there maybe some good practices in dealing such situations?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Questions containing words like "right," "good," "reasonable," and "acceptable" are not answerable unless you tell us specifically what those words mean within the context of your specific problem. In general, there is no "right" way; there is only the way that most effectively fulfills *your specific requirements.*

Answer (score 1):

Unlike in C where you can't start a thread with multiple argument (pthread void** param :D), Java thread only permit to run the method `run` with no argument. (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/877096 thanks @RobertHarvey).

You have no choice of using field to pass parameter to a Thread.

However you can decouple the DeviceDriver from its thread aspect, since on the abstract side, DevideDriver is not necesseraly one thread.

So you can move the method `run()` of *DeviceDriver* to a *DeviceDriverThread* and add a method run(MessageQueue queue) to *DeviceDriver*

This DeviceDriverThread will take as fields the *MessageQueue* and the concret *DeviceDriver* to run and this method run will do the following :

```
private MessageQueue queue;
private DeviceDriver deviceDriver;
public void run(){
     deviceDriver.run(queue);
}
```

I guess you will need the method stop in *DevideDriverThread* too.

Just think of it as a simple Adapter pattern.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/877096

Comment: @RobertHarvey exactly, i added the link, this is what I suggest that he can move away the thread aspect so he can have his DeviceDriver hierarchy not need a field but taking it as a parameter of the run() function (which is not anymore the one from Runnable interface).

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you hide queue inside `DeviceDriver` and expose needed methods (`get`, `clear`, whatever) by thread-safe delegation?

This way the user of your `DeviceDriver` class won't care about it's realization and will only use what is actually needs, and your `DeviceDriver` won't have unnecessary dependence.